# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Pagination' not found ... Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add ajax paging in `CI_pagination` class, but for this I want to create a class `MY_Pagination` which extends the CI_Pagination class but it gives error when I use this library by `$this->load->library('pagination');` in my controller:
and calling the test function in new MY_Pagination Class

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Pagination::test() ...`

I also added the line `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` in config.php
I changed the sub class name because of `Please note that all native CodeIgniter libraries are prefixed with CI_ so DO NOT use that as your prefix.` on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Here is my code

```
<?php
class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function test()
    {
       echo 'test';
    }
}
?>
```

This code is saved in a file MY_Pagination.php.

I read the document from https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html but this not works why?

Answer (score 1):

Load the `CI_Pagination` class before you try to extend it, so

```
$this->load->library('pagination'); // base class
$this->load->library('ajax_pagination'); // custom derived class
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you building a library for Pagination.

Codeigniter already has a pagination library

Refer this

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I want ajax pagination in it so I am extending the existing one.